# Changing the deprecated TabActivity

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm working on an android sample project, which makes use of TabActivity. But as this is deprecated now, I replaced it with the 'Fragment' activity. Now I don't know what to use, to replace,

`TabHost tabHost = getTabHost()`

which I had used while using TabActivity.

Also, `setContentView(R.layout.main)`

and `setClass()` in `intent = new Intent().setClass()` is giving an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Action Bar Sherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/). This open source library gives you an action bar for every Android Version down to 1.6

This enables you to create tabs in the Honeycomb style with the Honeycomb APIs, therefore you do not need to use the deprecated tab APIs.

Comment: There is at the moment nothing simpler if you want to use fragments as tab content and support Ice Cream Sandwich. Sadly the introduction of the ActionBar made a big difference in the Tab API. 
I would give Action Bar Sherlock a try. It will give your whole App the nice modern style of an ICS App and make tabs really easy.

Comment: ok thats fine. Ya I agree that they'll look great. thanks again.